# reading string with newlines and spaces

Tags: c, parsing, scanf, fgets

I am trying to parse a string from stdin such as this one `{  7  , 3,5 ,11, 8, 16, 4, 9, 2
,8, 4, 2}` ( there is a \n between 2 and 8 ).

I have made a function to extract the numbers and trim commas spaces and newlines (accepts char* as an input) but the problem is when I try to get input using scanf I can't get spaces so I used fgets instead but fgets will exit as soon as it sees \n.

Is there a way I can get a string from this ?

Comment: `char partA[199],partB[99]; fgets(partA,99,stream); fgets(partB,99,stream); partA[strlen(partA)-1] = 0; strcat (partA, partB);` <== it's in `partA`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fgets` to read the full line and use `strtok` to read the numbers. The example below will also treat `\n` as a comma `,`

```
char line[512];
char *buf = 0;
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
{
    if(!strstr(line, "{") && !buf)
        continue;

    if(!buf)
    {
        buf = strdup(line);
    }
    else
    {
        buf = realloc(buf, strlen(buf) + strlen(line) + 1);
        strcat(buf, line);
    }

    if(strstr(line, "}"))
    {
        char *token = strtok(buf, "{");
        strtok(buf, ",}\n");
        while(token)
        {
            int n = 0;
            sscanf(token, "%d", &n);
            printf("%d, ", n);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",}\n");
        }
        free(buf);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int nums[1000], count = 0;
char chr;
while(scanf("%c%d", &chr, &nums[count]) > 0) //there was at least one match
{
    if(chr == '}')
        break; //we have reached the end 
    if(chr != ',' && chr != '{')
        continue; //skip spaces (} is an exception)
    count++;
}
```